# how to hide sound recorder in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, audio-recording

I want to record sound on a Windows 7 computer using software called Sound recorder.

My question Is there any way to hide it

[image]

even i did that : Open windows Task Manager (Press Ctrl+Alt+Delete) and do a right click on the Sound Recorder task name and then select Minimize!

still not hidden

[image]
Thanks any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: forget what I wrote before. After some more investigation I found out that Soundrecorder natively supports this.

Either create a shortcut or batchfile or run directly from the commandline and specify the file and duration and it will silently run without window. It will be visible in the taskmanager under processes for that user but the old solution can even hide that upto a certain degree.

In the shortcut write the following:

```
soundrecorder /FILE <filename> /DURATION <hh:mm:ss>
```

for example:

```
soundrecorder /FILE c:\temp\output.wav /DURATION 0:0:10
```

Here's a step by step instruction on to creating something that will start sound recorder when windows starts.

1. Press the start orb to open the `start menu`.
2. Press `All Programs` to show all programs.
3. Scroll down to where it says `Startup`.
4. Right click the item Startup and select `open`

[image]

5. Rightclick on an empty area.
6. From the popup menu, go to the menu `New`, then select `Shortcut`

[image]

7. copy the text I've written above for the shortcut and paste it in the location field.
8. Change the duration time to your liking.

[image]

8. Press <kbd>Next</kbd>
9. Press <kbd>Finish</kbd>

And you're done. Do note that this will overwrite the wave file each time this is started. It can be changed so that everytime its run it will create a new file, but that will quickly create large files on the computer.

To output to a random file, you can set the file to c:\temp\output_%random%%random%.wav or perhaps even better, do this: c:\temp\output_%date%_%random%.wav

The new like will look like this:

```
soundrecorder /FILE c:\temp\output_%date%_%random%.wav /DURATION 0:0:10
```

---[ old solution ]------

*Start the program as a different user without desktop interaction will completely hide it from windows. In the task manager you can only see it if you choose "show processes from all users".*

In order to do this, create a 2nd account on the computer if it doesn't have at least 2 accounts, then use the runas /user:[username] /savecred "%SystemRoot%\system32\SoundRecorder.exe /file c:\output.wav /duration 1:00:00"

The first time you have to enter a password, but then it will store the password and a next time this password is used. You can remove this from the Credential Manager at a later stage if you desire so.

It will then record to c:\output.wav for a duration of 1 hour.

Comment: look interesting could you please detail that idea and support it with picture for each step

Comment: Sure. Give me a moment.

Comment: Found out SoundRecorder natively supports this, so I edited my post accordingly. Do you still need an image, or can you create a shortcut on your own, edit it, and paste the correct parameters in it?

Comment: please can you add picture for both method

Comment: Again nice! May I ask you where do you find it? I didn't see anything in its help document.

Comment: @TheGoodUser-Sp I googled for SoundRecorder commandline, and the first search result lead me to: http://www.7tutorials.com/record-audio-sound-recorder-windows-7 which has a section for the commandline parameters at the bottom. :) I tried it out to find out it hides the window for me.

Comment: @Educ I'll add an image later. I now have to solve a computer problem for one of our customers. Feel free to read the link provided in the above comment which has all the images you likely need. :)

Comment: @LPChip no problem take your time

Comment: @Educ I've written a step by step instruction set for you. I haven't done the extended set for using runas, as I'm pretty sure you don't really need that.

Answer (score 2):

Create a shortcut of the Sound Recorder. then do a right click on the shortcut and change its icon and set the run field on *Minimized*. Now, when you double click on the shortcut, you can see just the shape of your selected icon in task bar.

[image]

Comment: @ Thanks but still not hidden

Comment: @Educ Doesn't it minimized?!

Comment: it's minimized but it still shown in taskbar

Comment: @Educ Check my new answer.

Comment: Thanks bro but is there any way to turn it as spy  sound record

Answer (score 2):

Reference [Taskbar Hide - hide windows program 1.8](http://www.eusing.com/hidewindows/bosskey.htm)

> [image]
>
> - Hide windows program (applications) or /Show/Close //
>
>   Using Taskbar Hide you can hide any running application window. All you need to do is to select the application in the Taskbar Hide
>     list and click Hide icon or click mouse right button to popup the menu
>     and select hide item for the change to take effect. Taskbar Hide is
>     also able to hide/show/close the program windows quickly through
>     pressing a hotkey.
> - Hide/Show icons from the system tray /
>
>   You can hide some of the less used icons from the system tray. The operation is the same as to Hide/Show application windows. Now this
>     function supports windows me/2000/xp/vista/7.
> - Modify application windows order on taskbar
>
>   You can arrange the windows on taskbar according to your preference. Select the application in the Taskbar Hide list and use Up
>     and Down arrows to reorder the application windows. This feature
>     becomes useful when you want to put related application windows
>     together.
> - Stay on top window
>
>   You can select Always on top (topmost) or Normal (Non-topmost). The former places the selected window above all non-topmost windows,
>     and this window will maintains its topmost position even when it is
>     deactivated. The latter places the selected window above all other
>     non-topmost windows but below all topmost windows.
> - Minimize to tray
>
>   You can minimize any running application window to the system tray instead of an icon on your taskbar. You can bring the application
>     window back to normal by using Show, or double click left mouse button
>     on the icons or click right mouse button from the menu.
> - Hide taskbar
>
>   You can select to hide taskbar or Hide/Show any of the following: taskbar, start button, task window, system tray, and time clock.
> - Window Properties
>
>   You can find out more information of the selected window with the
>     Window Properties dialog  box. Such as window handle, class name,
>     process id, thread id, window style and  exstyle.
> - Maximize all windows
>
>   You can use Taskbar Hide to maximize all windows or only IE windows so
>     that they cover the entire screen. Also you can minimize all windows
>     to taskbar.
>
> Taskbar Hide is a freeware product, this means that you can download and use it for free.

Comment: now the problem is that software it self we can't hide it

Comment: It's impossible to hide something completely :/ Just because you can see it doesn't mean someone can't find the process ...

Comment: but the level at which it can be used will depend on the knowledge of the user